# calling an event before button check inside a view using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have view containing four radio button  and two button.
i have written code on click of button , but i want to check condition of radio button before button click but not able to find any idea how to do

```
$(document).on("click", "#btncrtn", function (e) { 
 var optname="";
 var checkedInput = $('input[name="ctype"]:checked').length;
 if(checkedInput == 0) {
    alert("Please Select one case type");
     return;
    } 
  else {
   if ($('#opn').is(':checked')) {                  
       optname="O";
        $('#CaseIdC').hide();
        }
   if ($('#lit').is(':checked')) {                       
       optname="L";
       $('#CaseIdC').hide();
        }
    if ($('#cun').is(':checked')) {                        
       optname="C";
       $('#CaseIdC').hide();
       }
    if ($('#oth').is(':checked')) {
       $('#CaseIdC').show();
       optname="T";  
       if ($('#CaseIdtxt').val()=="") 
         {
           alert("Please enter aims id");
           return;
         }
         }
});
```

i want a radio button  with id #oth to be checked  apart from condition #btncrtn click

```
 if ($('#oth').is(':checked')) {
    $('#CaseIdC').show();
});
```

how to achieve it.

Comment: How about using `change` event on radio ?

Comment: @Swati i have no idea how to use  that can you guide please ,how to do.

Comment: Just use `$('#oth').change(function() { //check if the radio is check hide or show div})`